# Send Email with Attachments located in same folder as the workbook

Tags: excel, vba, email, attachment, filedialog

I generate an Outlook HTML formatted email to send to the email address designated by cell.

I attach multiple files located in the same folder as the workbook with the FileDialog box.
I would like the initial folder that comes up to be the location of the current workbook.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim xStrFile As String
    Dim xFilePath As String
    Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xFileDlgItem As Variant
    Dim xOutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim xMailOut As Outlook.MailItem
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xMailOut = xOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    If xFileDlg.Show = -1 Then
        With xMailOut
            .Display
            .To = Range("C14").Value
            .Subject = Range("B6").Value & " " & Range("B7").Value & " - " & Range("B9").Value & " Tile Estimate"
            .HTMLBody = Range("B14").Value & "," & "<br/>" & vbCrLf & "Here is our tile estimate for the" & Range("B6").Value & " " & Range("B7").Value & " - " & Range("B9").Value & " project. Please respond to this email to confirm that you have received the proposal." & .HTMLBody
            For Each xFileDlgItem In xFileDlg.SelectedItems
                .Attachments.Add xFileDlgItem
            Next xFileDlgItem
            .Display
        End With
    End If
    Set xMailOut = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion however I have tried this already but all the links want you to provide the exact file path and I am trying to get the File Picker to open in the folder of where the Workbook is located.

Comment: Use one of those suggestions with `ThisWorkbook.Path`.

Answer (score 0):

Update, here is what I ended up using

```
Sub Email_1()


Dim xStrFile As String
    Dim xFilePath As String
    Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xFileDlgItem As Variant
    Dim xOutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim xMailOut As Outlook.MailItem
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xMailOut = xOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    xFileDlg.Filters.Clear
    xFileDlg.Filters.Add "pdf files", "*.pdf"
    xFileDlg.AllowMultiSelect = True
    xFileDlg.InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path
    
    If xFileDlg.Show = -1 Then
                              
        With xMailOut
         .Display
            .To = Range("C13").Value
            .Subject = Range("B5").Value & " " & Range("B6").Value & " - " & Range("B8").Value & " Tile Estimate"
            .HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:12.0pt'>" & Range("B13").Value & "," & "<br/>" & vbCrLf & "Here is our tile estimate for the " & Range("B5").Value & " " & Range("B6").Value & " - " & Range("B8").Value & " project. Please respond to this email to confirm that you have received the proposal." & .HTMLBody
                        For Each xFileDlgItem In xFileDlg.SelectedItems
                .Attachments.Add xFileDlgItem
            Next xFileDlgItem
            .Display
        End With      
                
            End If
    Set xMailOut = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```